# Without disabling browser security how can I read the response header token

Tags: response-headers, browser-security

I am developing a web application with login and signup page using angular4. I have a login form with username and password. After submitting login form I got rest api response, but I cant read the response headers.

NOTE: I can only read content-type from the response header. rest of them I cant read.

But when I disable the browser security, I am able to read all the response headers.

How can I read the response headers without disabling browser security?